# Maven and play framework 2 - Unknown packaging: play2

Tags: java, maven, playframework-2.0

I've trying to integrate maven and play2 by this guide http://cescoffier.github.io/maven-play2-plugin/maven/release/quickstart.html , but when i try to build project maven says:

```
Unknown packaging: play2
```

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot `<extensions>true</extensions>` within the plugin configuration?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>de.akquinet.innovation.play2</groupId>
   <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are talking about this: 
<build>...<plugins>...<plugin>...<extensions>true</extensions> ?

Comment: I've just copied all pom file from site and put it to mine project pom file.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've just updated my answer to make it more precise.